# Solaris: gdb a.out > run > opens subshell?

Tags: c, unix, gdb

Haven't found anything about this.

Trying to learn gdb and I get the feeling I'm doing something wrong.

I compile the c program with `gcc -g program.c -o a.out`

then use the command `gdb a.out` followed with `run` and this opens a subshell after warning me that it's running. If I type `a.out` as a command, then `ctrl+d` I'll drop back to gdb and get whatever message it wanted to throw at me. Without running the `a.out` after dropping out of the subshell, gdb acts like I didn't do anything at all.

All the tutorials I've seen shows that `run` within gdb will run the loaded program. Googling hasn't found me anything.

Setting breakpoints seems to be ignored as well.

What I doing wrong?

Comment: From what you have written it seems you are using gdb correctly and I do not know why a subshell would open. Are you setting breakpoints before you run?

Comment: I am. Example: I typed `gdb a.out` then `break 10` and got `Breakpoint 2 at <mem address>: file main.c, line 10` then hitting run drops me to a subshell in b.... oh holy crap. I'll answer it myself.

Answer (score 1):

I'm ridiculous.

The default shell is csh on our unix server. In my .cshrc I have an exec bash at the end of .cshrc to drop csh and load bash. The gdb output is in csh, and it's causing bash to load.

/derp

Comment: 0 down vote
 

Glad you figured it out. I asked my own derp question earlier today.